# What can we do with ip address?

Tags: ip

My question is basically is that if we know someones ip address which is static then what can we do that with static ip using cmd except pinging. I have tried to only ping and tracert and find domain

Comment: You can ping it, you can try to telnet or ssh to it, you can print it as a string in reverse order, you can even hand it over to a hacker group and pay them to DDoS it. *None* of those things are really related to programming per se (unless you ask a question on how to reverse the string version of it, but that's already been asked and answered). And, since programming is the raison d'être of this site, the question is almost certainly off topic.

Comment: thank u very much for a great explanation